# How to open multiple files from multiple org-links?

Tags: org-mode, buffers, org-link

```
* Headline 1
- [[https://orgmode.org/][Org-Mode]]
- [[https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/][GNU Emacs]]

* Headline 2
- [[~/tmp/file1.org][First file]]
- [[~/tmp/file2.org][Second file]]
```

When the pointer is on Headline 1, if I do `C-c C-o RET`, then two tabs will open in my web browser.

When the pointer is on Headline 2, if I do `C-c C-o RET`, then only `file1.org` will open. How to make the two files open?

Comment: Almost certainly a bug: please report it with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I reported the bug from version 28.2 `emacs -q`.

Comment: Thanks! I see that it is fixed in the [Org mode git repo](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=92f9135b3c3f4f5100747ac7a2f27efc55b8e9a8) in the main branch (and also in the [bugfix](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?h=bugfix&id=92f9135b3c3f4f5100747ac7a2f27efc55b8e9a8) branch, but I'm not sure when it will appear on the [Gnu package repo](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/org.html) - maybe this week, maybe next week (?)).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess it won't be part of the next Emacs release (29). I'm using Gnu/Linux Arch, so I'll get Emacs updated soon after the new version is out. How could one just update Org-Mode? Is it possible to do it with `use-package`? Shall I open a new post for this question?

Comment: It *should* be part of Emacs 29 whenever it is released. I think that will have the latest `main` in it (although you should take this with a grain of salt: I could very well be wrong). If you decide to install the package that's made from the `bugfix` branch, you should read the [Installation](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Installation) section of the manual - but heed the caveat: `Important: You need to do this in a session where no ‘.org' file has been visited, i.e., where no Org built-in function have been loaded. Otherwise autoload Org functions will mess up the installation.`

Comment: I can't help with `use-package`, but there should be plenty of questions on Emacs SE on installing Org mode from the package repo.